# Grails - Custom tag inside a standard Grails tag

Tags: grails, tags, include, taglib, gsp

It is possible to call a Grails' tag inside another one using the following synthax.

```
<g:aContainingGrailsTag value="${aContainedGrailsTag(attr:'whatever')}"
```

Is it possible to include a custom tag into a Grails tag using the exact same syntax. 
I am trying it this way:

```
<td class="${redOrGreen(number:'i')}"> </td>
```

but it does not work. 
Any insight on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this specific case, you can do it like this:

```
<td class="<yourNameSpace:redOrGreen number='i' />"> </td>
```

or in general:

```
<td class="${yourNameSpace.redOrGreen(number:'i')}"> </td>
```

Only for tags within `g:` can be called without namespace prefix.